# sudoers syntax for specifying a list of executables

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, passwords, sudo, sudoers

I want my user (username "wim" in group "wim") to be able to use `sudo apt-get` and `sudo dpkg` without needing admin password.

I tried editing sudoers file with sudo visudo, and I added in this line:

```
wim ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get, /usr/bin/dpkg
```

But it's not working, I still get asked for password.  What did I do wrong?

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10.